# SSH will always authenticate as root

Tags: ssh, authentication

```
# ssh -l admin 10.1.0.2
Warning: Permanently added '10.1.0.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@10.1.0.2's password:
```

Using "OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n" I want to connect to a remote host, but what ever I try, it always reverts the login to root. Configuration files has been renamed to ensure that no User option is being applied. The only hint I get is this line:

```
debug1: Authenticating to 10.1.0.2:22 as 'root'
```

-- EDIT --

To provide more information, here is a debug output up to the point where SSH decides to authenticate as root, though told not to do so.

```
xxxxxxx:~$ ssh -vvv -p4711 foo@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 4711.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4711 as 'root'
debug3: put_host_port: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:4711
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:4711
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
```

As you can see, there are no configuration file options applied. What puzzles me most is, that on a different host using the same ssh client version, it works. I still think that I'm missing something fundamental. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Typically running the ssh client with `-v` and/or `-vv`  debug flags will show which configuration files get applied and  in what order, for example `debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config` 
`debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for ...` and debug1: `Reading configuration data /Users/diya/.ssh/config`  - Does that list any particulars?

Comment: No. I've renamed the files that has been applied to test this, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, but one configuration file did get applied: `debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config` - please check its content...

Comment: Usually, SSH says something like ```debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *``` if it applies an option. In the output it just reads the file, but doesn't seem to apply anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, for taking your time... I've found the cause of this behaviour:

```
alias ssh='ssh -l root -o "PreferredAuthentications publickey,password"'
```

Didn't know, that a package set this alias in /etc/bash.bashrc.

Kind regards...

Comment: Ouch. That's really bad. Which package was responsible for that?

Comment: Don't worry. It's in one of our companies package, which are not public.